# JavaScript: I need to create questions on matrix operations like addition, multiplication, etc. How to display the matrix on the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix

The desired display should be in the form of a 2D matrix of the size nxn where n:2 to 4. I want the matrices to be able to generate random numbers as its elements. The questions that need to be solved should be as shown in the image in the link below.
[Matrix operation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcKNZ.jpg)
The code  I've tried so far is:

```
var mat = randomMat(4,4);
var n = randElem(2)+2;
console.log(n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    var idn="mat";
    document.getElementById(idn).innerHTML = ("<tr id='row'"+i+">a</tr>");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        var idName = "row"+(j+1);
        console.log(idName);
        document.getElementById(idName).innerHTML = ("<td id='col'"+j+">b</td>");
    }
}   

function randomMat(a,b){
    var arr = new Array(a);
    for(var i=0;i<a;i++){
        arr[i]= new Array(b);
        for(var j=0;j<b;j++){
                arr[i].push(randElem(10));
        }
    }console.log(arr);
}

function randElem(n){
    var elem = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
    return elem;
}
```

As of now I'm not able to display the matrix in browser and insert the generated random elements in the matrix.

Comment: better use with `TeX`  https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/

Comment: could you show me a sample code please. for a simple matrix addition of two 2x2 matrices

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01m5jj90/ refer the snippet for 2*2 matrix

Comment: seems to be working... thanks...

Comment: for more information about kindly visit http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

> As of now I'm not able to display the matrix in browser and insert the
>   generated random elements in the matrix.

Your code works fine for generating the array and numbers. The problem is how you are trying to get that into the DOM. Don't use `innerHTML`, as that would get messy with all string concatenation and gets difficult to manage. Use `createElement` to create the cells and generate the table, and the `appendChild` to add that to the DOM.

Like this:

```
function generate(elem, rows, cols) {
    var matrix = getMatrix(rows, cols), 
        elem = document.getElementById(elem), 
        table;
    table = document.createElement('table');
    for (i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (j=-1; j <= cols; j++) { 
            var col = document.createElement('td');
            col.textContent = matrix[i][j];
            row.appendChild(col);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    elem.appendChild(table);
}
```

*Note: The inner loop creates extra cells to the table to make the bracket notation easy.*

**Working Example Snippet:**

```js
var min = -5, max = 25;

generate('matrix-01', 3, 3);
generate('matrix-02', 2, 2);

function generate(elem, rows, cols) {
  var matrix = getMatrix(rows, cols), 
      elem = document.getElementById(elem), 
      table;
  table = document.createElement('table');
  for (i=0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j=-1; j <= cols; j++) { 
      var col = document.createElement('td');
      col.textContent = matrix[i][j];
      row.appendChild(col);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
  elem.appendChild(table);
}

function getMatrix(size) {
  var matrix = new Array(size), 
      idx = size, 
      args;
  for (i=0; i < size; i++) { matrix[i] = getRandom(); }
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      while(idx--) { matrix[size-1 - idx] = getMatrix(args); }
  }
  return matrix;
}


function getRandom() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.math { 
  font-size: 1.2em; font-family: serif; font-style: italic; 
  color: #333; vertical-align: middle; margin: 16px;
}
.math div, .math span { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
.math table { 
  display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 1px solid #999; border-right: 1px solid #999; 
  font-family: monospace; font-style: normal; margin-right: 16px;
}
.math table td { text-align: right; padding: 4px 8px; }
.math table tr:first-child td:first-child, 
.math table tr:first-child td:last-child 
{ border-top: 1px solid #999; }
.math table tr:last-child td:first-child, 
.math table tr:last-child td:last-child
{ border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
```

```html
<div class="math">
  <span>x = </span>
  <div id="matrix-01"></div> 
  <span>y = </span>
  <div id="matrix-02"></div> 
</div>
```

**Fiddle Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o1csa8gq/**

*Note 2: The function to generate the arrays is a generic one. It can be used as-is to create n-dimensional arrays. Just call it like this: `getMatrix(4)` or `getMatrix(4, 4)` or `getMatrix(4, 2, 3...)`.*